# Proving that I own the private key associated to a public key

Tags: ssh, putty, github

After changing job, I have lost access to my former professional GitHub account. To prove that the account is indeed mine, GitHub is asking me this:

> If you have access to any of the private SSH keys associated with your account, could you please run the following command:
>
> ```
> ssh -T git@github.com verify
> ```
>
> and then provide us with the result?

I'm on Windows (and I do have Git For Windows installed) but I use PuTTY's Pageant for authentication. I tried loading my private key into Pageant and typing the requested command but all I'm getting is

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

If I run the same command with the private key of a GitHub account I do control, I get the same error so it doesn't seem to be related to my keys at all.

Am I misunderstanding what they ask? How else can I prove that I own the private key corresponding to the public key associated to the GitHub account I lost control of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot log in as git. They ask you only to execute command without trying to establish interactive session.

Windows alternative would probably be:

```
plink.exe -T git@github.com verify
```

(Plink comes in PuTTY package)

Comment: PuTTY `-m` switch accepts a command file not a command. --- PuTTY comes with command-line utility `plink`, which has the same command-line syntax as OpenSSH `ssh`. So PuTTY equivalent is actually `plink -T git@github.com verify`

Comment: Awesome, thanks @MartinPrikryl. If you create an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I've edited this answer, please accept it.